# routerLinkActiveOptions testing

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't seem to figure out how to set the *.component.spect.ts file for a component that is using the `[routerLinkActiveOptions]` directive. I keep getting this error:

```
Can't bind to 'routerLinkActiveOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
```

This is the spec file:

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';

import {TranslatePipeMock} from '@common/services/translate/translate.pipe.mock';

import {NavigationComponent} from './navigation.component';

describe('NavigationComponent', () => {
    let component: NavigationComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavigationComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule,
            ],
            declarations: [
                NavigationComponent,
                TranslatePipeMock,
            ],
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavigationComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to test the directive within this component you might want to have a look at https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/directives/

But assuming you only want to unit test your component you should set schemas: [NO_ERROR_SCHEMA] within ur TestBed setup - eg just add this below the declarations

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
        ],
        declarations: [
            NavigationComponent,
            TranslatePipeMock,
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
        .compileComponents();
}));
```

This schema allows the compiler to ignore missing directives or subcomponents if you only want to test the behaviour of the component under test.

The error occurs because by default the unit test tries to resolve everything used. Since the directive is set inthe template but not found within your TestBed declerstuons the compiler complains.

Actually the offical docs cover things pretty thouroughly https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: I don't think this is exactly a very good approach. I can of course mock this directive, but I thought angular had something specific for this, something like RouterTestingModule.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You only have to mock the directive if you want to tesr it. But since its an angular directive you don‘t need to test its functionality since its already been tested. So you only set the schema to shallow test your own conponent. If you go with the shema approach, you don‘t have to mock the directive.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Isn't `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` in general considered not a very good approach? Will it suppress other errors?

Comment: Well you need to be careful of course since it does suppress any compile errors. that‘s true. But it is the way to go if you only want to test the logic in one component regardless of its dependencies. Please have a look at the angular documentation (shallow testing) they explained that pretty well.